# orangehrm 3.3.3 installation and configurations error on linux

Tags: installation, centos, orangehrm

For couple of days I am trying to install latest stable open source version 3.3.3 of OrangeHrm on linux. I have tried on CentOS 7, Ubuntu Server 16.04, Ubuntu Server 14.04. All these I installed on VirtualBox. I followed different guideline explained on different sites. 
For example:
https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-orangehrm-on-ubuntu-14-04/

On each of the installation, when I access both inside virtual machine or from host, I end up with internal server error with blank page.

The error occurs after I enter the database details.

I tried with both existing blank database and with new database also. Both with root DB user as well as with other privileged user.

I would preferable like to have it installed on CentOS.

I think it must be very simple installation and I might be missing some silly simple detail.

Any guidelines and resources would highly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to [ubuntu.se]

Comment: Solved. The trick was not to create database and database user and let OrangeHRM web installer create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The trick was not to create database and database user and let OrangeHRM web installer create it